# Why does the order of Ring middleware need to be reversed?

Tags: clojure, ring

I'm writing some middleware for Ring and I'm really confused as to why I have to reverse the order of the middleware.

I've found this [blog post](http://squirrel.pl/blog/2012/04/10/ring-handlers-functional-decorator-pattern/) but it doesn't explain why I have to reverse it.

Here's a quick excerpt from the blog post:

```
(def app
  (wrap-keyword-params (wrap-params my-handler)))
```

The response would be:

```
{; Trimmed for brevity
 :params {"my_param" "54"}}
```

Note that the wrap keyword params didn't get called on it because the params hash didn't exist yet. But when you reverse the order of the middleware like so:

```
(def app
  (wrap-params (wrap-keyword-params my-handler)))

{; Trimmed for brevity
 :params {:my_param "54"}}
```

It works.

Could somebody please explain why you have to reverse the order of the middleware?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It helps to visualize what middleware actually is.

```
(defn middleware [handler]
  (fn [request]
    ;; ...
    ;; Do something to the request before sending it down the chain.
    ;; ...
    (let [response (handler request)]
      ;; ...
      ;; Do something to the response that's coming back up the chain.
      ;; ...
      response)))
```

That right there was pretty much the a-ha moment for me.

What's confusing at first glance is that middleware isn't applied to the request, which is what you're thinking of.

Recall that a Ring app is just a function that takes a request and returns a response (which means it's a handler):

```
((fn [request] {:status 200, ...}) request)  ;=> response
```

Let's zoom out a little bit. We get another handler:

```
((GET "/" [] "Hello") request)  ;=> response
```

Let's zoom out a little more. We find the `my-routes` handler:

```
(my-routes request)  ;=> response
```

Well, what if you wanted to do something before sending the request to the `my-routes` handler? You can wrap it with another handler.

```
((fn [req] (println "Request came in!") (my-routes req)) request)  ;=> response
```

That's a little hard to read, so let's break out for clarity. We can define a function that returns that handler. Middleware are functions that take a handler and wrap it another handler. It doesn't return a response. It returns a handler that can return a response.

```
(defn println-middleware [wrapped-func]
  (fn [req]
    (println "Request came in!")
    (wrapped-func req)))

((println-middleware my-route) request)  ;=> response
```

And if we need to do something before even `println-middleware` gets the request, then we can wrap it again:

```
((outer-middleware (println-middleware my-routes)) request)  ;=> response
```

The key is that `my-routes`, just like your `my-handler`, is the only named function that actually takes the request as an argument.

One final demonstration:

```
(handler3 (handler2 (handler1 request)))  ;=> response
((middleware1 (middleware2 (middleware3 handler1))) request)  ;=> response
```

I write so much because I can sympathize. But scroll back up to my first `middleware` example and hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: I would give you 10 upvotes if I could, this helped a lot. This is similar to Pedestal's [interceptors](http://pedestal.io/reference/interceptors) but all in one function.

Answer (score 14):

The ring middleware is a series of functions which when stacked up return a handler function.

The section of the article that answers your question:

> In case of Ring wrappers, typically we have “before” decorators that
>   perform some preparations before calling the “real” business function.
>   Since they are higher order functions and not direct function calls,
>   they are applied in reversed order. If one depends on the other, the
>   dependent one needs to be on the “inside”.

Here is a contrived example:

```
(let [post-wrap (fn [handler]
                  (fn [request]
                    (str (handler request) ", post-wrapped")))
      pre-wrap (fn [handler]
                 (fn [request]
                   (handler (str request ", pre-wrapped"))))
      around (fn [handler]
               (fn [request]
                 (str (handler (str request ", pre-around")) ", post-around")))
      handler (-> (pre-wrap identity)
                  post-wrap
                  around)]
  (println (handler "(this was the input)")))
```

This prints and returns:

```
(this was the input), pre-around, pre-wrapped, post-wrapped, post-around
nil
```

Answer (score 6):

As you may know the ring `app` is actually just a function that receives a `request` map and returns a `response` map.

In the first case the order in which the functions are applied is this:

```
request -> [wrap-keyword-params -> wrap-params -> my-handler] -> response
```

[`wrap-keyword-params`](http://clojuredocs.org/ring/ring.middleware.keyword-params/wrap-keyword-params) looks for the key `:params` in the `request` but it's not there since [`wrap-params`](http://clojuredocs.org/ring/ring.middleware.params/wrap-params) is the one who adds that key based on the "*urlencoded parameters from the query string and form body*".

When you invert the order of those two:

```
request -> [wrap-params -> wrap-keyword-params -> my-handler] -> response
```

You get the desired result since once the `request` gets to `wrap-keyword-params`, `wrap-params` has already added the corresponding keys.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by danneu is nice, but it only really "clicked" for me after I visualized it in code to see how the chaining of middleware really looks like without the "->" threading macro magic ([here's a link](https://clojure.org/guides/threading_macros) if you're not familiar with it). This is what I ended up with:

Let's say you have a request handler that looks like this:

```
(def amazing-handler
  (-> #'some-amazing-fn
      some-mware
      another-mware
      one-more-mware))
```

^^ The above handler, written without using a threading macro, would look like this (and I'm extending the indentation on purpose, so it is visually easier to understand which request belongs to which handler):

```
(def amazing-handler 
  (one-more-mware
                (another-mware
                        ((some-mware #'some-amazing-fn) request-from-another-mware)
                    request-from-one-more-mware)
   original-request))
```

^^ The above is a style of code that requires us to read it from inside out (which sometimes is hard to follow), the threading macros ([->](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E) and [->>](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E%3E)) allow us to read code in a natural left-to-right way, but it requires understanding on our part of how exactly it allows us to compose code in this "natural" way behind the scene.

Here's a more complete example:

```
;; For reference: this is how the end result of the entire "threading" looks like:
;; (((#'some-amazing-fn req-from-up-passed-down) req-from-up-passed-down) original-request)

(defn some-amazing-fn [req] ;; this "req" is the one that will get passed to this function from "some-mware"
  (println "this is the final destination of the req", req)
  (ring.util.http-response/ok {:body "some funny response"}))


(defn one-more-mware [some-argument] ;; the "some-argument" in this case is (another-mware (some-mware #'some-amazing-fn))
  (fn [req] ;; the "req" here is the original request generated by the ring adaptors and passed to this chain of middleware
    (println "|--> from fn inside one-more-mware")
    (some-argument req))) ;; here we provide the another-mware with the request that it will then pass down the chain of middleware, you can imagine that chain, at this point in time, to look like this:
    ;; ((another-mware (some-mware #'some-amazing-fn)) req)


(defn another-mware [dunno-something] ;; the "dunno-something" in this case is (some-mware #'some-amazing-fn)
  (fn [req] ;; the "req" here is passed from one-more-mware function
    (println "|--> from fn inside another-mware")
    (dunno-something req))) ;; here we are passing the "req" down the line to the (some-mware #'some-amazing-fn), so the entire thing behind the scenes, at this point in time, looks like this:
    ;; ((some-mware #'some-amazing-fn) req)


(defn some-mware [some-handler] ;; the "some-handler" arg here refers to #'some-amazing-fn
  (fn [req] ;; the "req" here is passed to this function from another-mware function
    (println "|--> from fn inside some-mware")
    (some-handler req))) ;; here is where we are passing a "req" argument to the #'some-amazing-fn, so behind the scenes it could be thought of as looking like this:
    ;; (#'some-amazing-fn req)


(def amazing-handler
  (-> #'some-amazing-fn
      some-mware
      another-mware
      one-more-mware))

;; |--> from fn inside one-more-mware
;; |--> from fn inside another-mware
;; |--> from fn inside some-mware
;; |--> this is the final destination of the req {.. .. ..}
```